# How many rows were deleted?

Tags: django, django-models, mysql, django-orm

Is it possible to check how many rows were deleted by a query?

```
queryset = MyModel.object.filter(foo=bar)
queryset.delete()
deleted = ...
```

Or should I use transactions for that?

```
@transaction.commit_on_success
def delete_some_rows():
    queryset = MyModel.object.filter(foo=bar)
    deleted = queryset.count()
    queryset.delete()
```

PHP + MySQL example:

```
mysql_query('DELETE FROM mytable WHERE id < 10');
printf("Records deleted: %d\n", mysql_affected_rows());
```

Comment: Hmm, well `queryset.delete()` should delete `len(queryset)` number of objects, but to get the number of affected rows from the MySQL you should use [MySQLdb](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html) driver directly i think.

Answer (score 4):

There are many situations where you want to know how many rows were deleted, for example if you do something based on how many rows were deleted. Checking it by performing a COUNT creates extra database load and is not atomic.

The `queryset.delete()` method immediately deletes the object and returns the number of objects deleted and a dictionary with the number of deletions per object type.
Check the docs for more details: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/db/queries/#deleting-objects

Answer (score 0):

Actual rows affected you could view with `SELECT row_count()`.
First of all `qs.count()` and `cursor.rowcount` is not same things!

In MySQL with InnoDB with REPEATABLE READ (default mode) READ queries and WRITE queries view **!!DIFFERENT!!!** querysets!

READ queries read from old snapshot, while WRITE queries view actual committed data, like they works in `READ COMMITTED` mode.